# Dropdownlist with a list of Models

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm  trying to save multiple models but have problem with the dropdownlist of the model.

I got the following error: **No information ViewData type 'IEnumerable ' with key '[0]. TypeBienId'.**

Here are some files:

Controller GET:

```
public ActionResult RDummy()
{
    List<BI> bis = new List<BI>();
    BI bi1 = new BI();

    ViewBag.TypeBienId = new SelectList(db.TypeBiens, "TypeBienId", "cnom");
    bis.Add(bi1);
    return View(bis);
}
```

My View:

```
@model IEnumerable<SIBI.Models.BI> 
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
   @Html.EditorForModel()
   <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Crear" />
   </p> 
}
```

My Template in the EditorTemplates Folder:

```
@model SIBI.Models.BI
@Html.DropDownList("TypeBienId", String.Empty)<br /> 
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TypeBienId)
```

Any ideas of what the problem is and how to resolved?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use something more like: @Html.DropDownList("TypeBienId", ViewBag.TypeBienId); or something? Where are you passing it your selectlist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this in your EditorTemplate:

```
@Html.DropDownList("TypeBienId", ViewBag.TypeBienId);
```

Comment: Works only if apply a cast. @Html.DropDownList("TypeBienId", **(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)** ViewBag.TypeBienId);